# Automation on lead merge

Tags: leads, merge

I have a simple requirement of capturing the "newest" created date when two leads are merged. As far as I can tell the only way to detect a lead merge would be in delete trigger and look for `MasterRecordId` being set.  Is there someway to detect the merge using a workflow or process builder?

Also, while the docs state the `CreatedDate` of the oldest record is always kept, does this mean the newest record is always deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `after delete` trigger via `MasterRecordId` is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm) to be the only way to trigger on a merge:

> If your application requires special handling for deleted records that occur as a result of a merge, you need to use the after delete trigger event.

This would be the place to grab their `CreatedDate` values and populate the newest onto the winning record. Be aware that not all of the deleted records in the `after delete` trigger's context variables are necessarily from a single merge operation, or even all from merges period.

If you wanted to detect the merge in workflow or Process Builder, you could use a very simple `after delete` trigger to, for example, populate a `Merged_Ids__c` field with the losing records' Ids, and fire on that change. However, your process/workflow would not be able to capture data from the losing, and already deleted, records.

During a merge, the `update` trigger is fired on the winning records and the `before delete` trigger on the losing records, but no merge information is available during those trigger invocations, so you cannot detect that it's anything other than a normal update or deletion.

The newest record may or may not be deleted during a merge; it depends on which record is selected as the winning record.

Comment: great answer.  I was afraid that last statement would be true. Makes implementing this simple requirement much more complex unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately I've found that almost anything merge-related ends up being fairly complex to implement!